# SVD: $\mbox{im}(A)$ and $\ker(A)$ as orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, svd

In Gilbert Strang's book in the SVD chapter, he states that $u$ and $v$ give the bases for the image and kernel of a matrix.

Say we have a matrix $A$ that has rank $r$.

Why is it that the orthonormal basis of $Im(A)$ can be written as  $u_{1}, \dots, u_{r}$? and the orthonormal basis of $\ker(A)$ can be written as $v_{r+1}, \dots, v_{n}$?

If we decompose matrix $A$ in SVD form we will have $U \Sigma V^{T}$.

Edit:
$A \in R^{n \times m}$, $U \in R^{n \times n}$, $\Sigma \in R^{n \times m}$, $V \in R^{m \times m}$
$$
A = U \Sigma V^{T}  =  \begin{pmatrix} | & & | \\ u_{1} & \dots & u_{n} \\ | & & | \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \ddots & 0 \\ 0& 0 & \sigma_{n} \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix} - & \vec{v}_{1}^T& - \\  & \vdots &  \\ -& \vec{v}_{m}^T & - \end{pmatrix} 
$$

If rank is r then the entries in the diagonal after $\sigma_{r}$ is $0$. So the Ker would be associated with the singular values $\sigma_{r+1}, \dots ,\sigma_{n}$?

Comment: See edit  please

Comment: I was thinking of something like $$\mathrm A = \mathrm U \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm U_1 & \mathrm U_2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \Sigma_1 & \mathrm O\\ \mathrm O & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm V_1^{\top}\\ \mathrm V_2^{\top}\end{bmatrix} =  \mathrm U_1 \Sigma_1 \mathrm V_1^{\top}$$

Comment: Yes thats assuming rank is 1 right? So the basis for the image would span $u_1$ and the basis for the kernel would span $v_2$. My question is why that is the case? Or I guess I cant see it right now mathematically

Comment: No, $\Sigma_1$ is $r \times r$. My previous comment contains all the information you need. It shows that the image of $\rm A$ is spanned by the $r$ columns of $\mathrm U_1$. It also shows that the null space of $\rm A$ is spanned by the $n-r$ columns of $\mathrm V_2$.

Comment: @Probability1 The objects in Rodrigo's comment aren't vectors but matrices. The rank remains $r$.